# how to fetch all files from adb with powershell and C#

Tags: c#, powershell, adb

Hi I have automation code in c# that I need to check if the database files are encrypted, but first I need to download the files into my machine.

```
    try
    {
        string path = new DirectoryInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).Parent.Parent.FullName;

        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(path + "\\powershell\\");
        using (PowerShell pshell = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            pshell.AddCommand("adb pull \"/data/data/app.name.tt/files/Database\"");
            //pshell.AddScript(path + "\\powershell\\AdbPull.Ps1");
            pshell.Invoke();
        }
    }
    catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The specified directory does not exist. {0}", e);
    }
```

first how do I know to where the files are downloaded ? second how to save to specific folder ?

Comment: You need to specify the download location as second parameter in the `adb pull` command. Without that, the file(s) are downloaded to the location `adb.exe` is in.

Comment: i'm but i do not have permission even i'm adb root

Comment: ..then where is the output path in your `adb pull` command?

Comment: In the parameter path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options to do that:

#### Use plain Process (recommended)

```cs
var adbPath = "C:/Program Files/ADB/adb.exe";
var command = "pull";
var whatToPull = "\"/storage/77F1-1BF3/sht/1.jpg\"";
var whereToPull = "\"C:/Users/picolino/adb/downloads\"";

Process.Start(adbPath, $"{command} {whatToPull} {whereToPull}");
```

#### Use PowerShell (your case)

```cs
var adbPath = "C:/Program Files/ADB/adb.exe";
var command = "pull";
var whatToPull = "\"/storage/77F1-1BF3/sht/1.jpg\"";
var whereToPull = "\"C:/Users/picolino/adb/downloads\"";

using (var pShell = PowerShell.Create())
{
    pShell.AddScript($"& '{adbPath}' {command} {whatToPull} {whereToPull}");
    pShell.Invoke();
}
```